# Rotate and changing position of view in same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, rotation, transform

I have an app and I need to reproduce a dice animation. Everytime when the dices are rolled I should change a little bit his position on X axis and his rotation.

The dice is an `UIButton` inside of an `UIView` with 16 pixels bigger! When the user rolls I create an animation for rotating and in the same time I animate the change of X view value. When the animation is finished I try to fix a random stop position.

Take a look of my code to understand better.

This is my rotating animation:

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
animation.duration = 0.2;
animation.repeatCount = 2;
[dice.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];

int min = -20;
int maxim = 20;
int rndValue = min + arc4random() % (maxim - min);

// Here I change x value;
CGRect rct = dice.superview.frame;
rct.origin.x = n + rndValue;
rct.size.width = dice.superview.bounds.size.width;
rct.size.height = dice.superview.bounds.size.height;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
     dice.superview.frame = rct;
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
     //Here, after the animation is done, i want to put a random rotation value.
     float degrees = arc4random() % 30;
     dice.superview.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
     dice.superview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI/180);
}];
```

My problem is than everytime(expect first one when I roll) the dices(views too) becomes smaller, because the size of view frame is changing and I can't found the problem or any other solution. 
PS:If I use just one of these( rotating or changing X axis value) the dices keeps the same size.

I search already a lot online but nothing useful for me. Anyone have an idea, please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer for my problem and I post my solution here, maybe others people will meet same issue.

The problem become from dice moving. 
When I move the dice I change the frame of it, that was my mistake. The problem it's solved if you will change the center point of dice

Replace frame animation change with :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    dice.superview.center = CGPointMake((self.view.frame.size.width - CGRectGetMaxX(imageBack.frame)) / 2 + rndValue + CGRectGetMaxX(imageBack.frame), dice.superview.center.y);
}completion:^(BOOL finished){

}];
```

Anyway, there are my values.. you can put whatever you want there!

Hope it helps